# Intel XDK Google API JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, intel-xdk

I'd like to use the Google Url Shortener API within a crossplatform App developed using Intel XDK.
At least in the emulator, no SOP seems to be enforced.
Anyway, I get this response:

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\n \"error\": {\n  \"errors\": [\n   {\n    \"domain\": \"global\",\n    \"reason\": \"required\",\n    \"message\": \"Required parameter: shortUrl\",\n    \"locationType\": \"parameter\",\n    \"location\": \"shortUrl\"\n   }\n  ],\n  \"code\": 400,\n  \"message\": \"Required parameter: shortUrl\"\n }\n}\n","responseJSON":{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"required","message":"Required parameter: shortUrl","locationType":"parameter","location":"shortUrl"}],"code":400,"message":"Required parameter: shortUrl"}},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"
```

Code:

```
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: { longUrl: "firec.at" }, 
        success: function (data) {
                $("#txtUsernameLogin").val(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function(data)
        {
             $("#txtUsernameLogin").val(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
```

Looks like it's not sending the longUrl param. I have no idea why that fails, and appreciate any advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because jQuery does not convert object in JSON string automatically. You can use `JSON.stringify` :

```
data: JSON.stringify({ longUrl: "firec.at" }),
```

Note that `JSON.stringify` is not available on all browsers. You may want to use a cross browser jQuery plugin to do that.

By the way, it's look like you want to do a POST, so you may need to add this too :

```
type : 'POST',
```

By default, jQuery does a GET.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed. I tried post already, but got an error message telling me that "form-encoded data is not supported". With post + JSON.stringify it works fine.